# Open and edit a MXML file in Flex Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Can anybody give me some quick advice on how to open an mxml file?  Been using Actionscript for a while, but new to Flex.

I've a project that i've been asked to make a quick change to with 3 folders and a mxml file, but have no idea how to open and edit them with Flex!

Any advice very welcome.

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open an MXML file in any text editor.  Once you make change, you'll have to recompile them using the command line compiler included in the Flex SDK.

Many people use Flash Builder, an eclipse based IDE From Adobe which makes the recompilation process a lot easier.  Alternative to Flash Builder exist, including FDT, IntelliJ, and Amethyst.

> how to open and edit them with Flex!

This question seems to lead to a misunderstanding of what Flex is.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785572/can-somebody-explain-in-a-few-sentences-how-these-technologies-relate-flex-flas), and it's answers, should help.  When people talk about Flex, they usually are referring to either the Flex Framework or the Flex SDK.  You wouldn't use either of those to open or edit a file.